# Parsing malformed JSON with double quotes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a server with sometimes serves me a bad JSON with double quotes inside string like bellow:

```
{
  "key1":"xx",
  "bad_stuff":"bad "bad"bad",
  "key2":"xx",
  "date":"2015-08-13"
}
```

Is there a way how can I fix above JSON? I was thinking about regexp to find all `"` which are not followed by `\s*}`, `\s*,` or `\s*:`.

Comment: Obviously, you want to arrange to have the server fixed. In the meantime, if it sends you broken JSON, the best you can do *mitigate*. You can't properly correct. You can come up with some rules to help with some of it, but for instance if the bad data happens to fit those rules... I think I'd be pretty reluctant to go down that road.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the sever side is fixing this for more than half a year, that is why I want to do something with it. But You are of course right

Answer (score 0):

The [`dirty-json` package](https://github.com/RyanMarcus/dirty-json) can handle this example without any trouble. Try the demo here: http://ryanmarcus.github.io/dirty-json/

(I am the author of the package.)